# PHP Searching in value array in Faster way

Tags: php, arrays, xml, laravel

This is just a quick question. I've looking for a fastest way to search value in array.Here's the value that i've been looking for :

```
      $array_to_search =  (object) array("52688", "81902");//came from database
```

and now i have huge amount data from XML. Here`s the array when i converted from XML.

```
      $array_to_search_in = Model::dataFromXMLconvertedintoArray();
```

And when i print this array the result is like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 52688
            [category] => Accessories & Promos
            [manufacturer] => Liberty Bags
            [manufacturer_sku] => 8881
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
             [product_id] => 52689
            [category] => Accessories & Promos
            [manufacturer] => Liberty Bags
            [manufacturer_sku] => 8881
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
             [product_id] => 52688
            [category] => Accessories & Promos
            [manufacturer] => Liberty Bags
            [manufacturer_sku] => 8881
        )
  And soon up to a hundreds data..
```

My goal is to "Select all from $array_to_search_in where product_id in  $array_to_search"

Since that the data came from xml (API) it loads very slow. Currently , I  am using foreach and unset function of php to filter the huge array and get the selected item i wanted to get but i think the foreach also the cause why the loading is more slower.

Comment: If array is sorted you can use Binary Search as it's complexity is O(log N), so if you have around 1000 items you can find an item in less than 10 operations

Answer (score 0):

As the array is not sorted, you must run through the entire array once. You could append a new array instead of unset() using the array_push() method.

With slight modification you could use [the array_keys() function (PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just don't shoot yourself in the foot by creating an array from the XML too early:

Use an xpath query on the XML before creating the array.

Then create the array from the query result.

Then the array will only contain the data you're interested in and not just all data you need to filter afterwards.

Comment: ouch, I've created an array directly from XML, i don't how to do that.

Comment: I know, that's why I answered this way. first add another method to that *model* so that you're able to *query* the data you're looking for, You can take care of the actual xpath query later, most important thing is that you pass the parameter(s) you want to query for. As you have not shown these in your question, I was not able to make them part of my answer. For querying XML documents, there is a distinct language for it: *Xpath*, every good PHP XML library supports version 1.0 of that language.